# Liquid Staking Unclaimed Reward via Polkadot.js

Tags: polkadot-js, staking

we would like to know if there is any solution to get the amount of the unclaimed rewards for nominationPool via Polkadot.js extrinsics.

Please help. Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use this `api.query.nominationPools.rewardPools`, from the [docs](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/substrate/storage#rewardpoolsu32-optionpalletnominationpoolsrewardpool):

> Reward pools. This is where there rewards for each pool accumulate. When a members payout is claimed, the balance comes out fo the reward pool. Keyed by the bonded pools account.

Comment: Additionally, to get the reward of a specific user, you can use this runtime API: https://polkadot.js.org/docs/substrate/runtime#pendingrewardsmember-accountid-balance